# How to run Outlook rule than message moved to folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I would like to run some Outlook rule, which will be run than  user moves a message from Inbox to some folder.

Answer (score 2):

It seems I found an answer to my own question :)
I have to define the following macro and do that I want in myOlItems_ItemAdd method

```
Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items

Public Sub Application_Startup()

' Reference the items in the Inbox. Because myOlItems is declared
' "WithEvents" the ItemAdd event will fire below.
 Set myOlItems = Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
 Set ee = Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("MyTestFolder")
 Set myOlItems = ee.Items
End Sub

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

 Debug.Print (Item.Subject)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook provides a predefined list of events that can trigger a rule to fire.  If you cannot find one that will do what you want younare probably out of luck.  While I suspect you can write your own COM plugin for this it is not for the average person.

Comment: Thank for the answer. Could you point me to some COM plugin sample?