# Outlook limits how many email rules I can have. How can I get around this?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, rules

I am using Microsoft Outlook 2010. I received a several hundred automated emails a day and rely on Outlook rules to help me organize them and stay sane. I have run into a problem where Outlook will not allow me to have rules that exceed [a certain size](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other/how-many-rules-can-i-have-in-outlook-why-is-there/53d7e596-5831-4c0a-926c-3e84c9f0f05f) in whatever format they are stored in, and this is impacting my workflow.

I have compacted as many rules as I can, but I may hit this limit again.  Is there a way to circumvent this limit, and have my email be sorted by as many rules as I want?

Comment: Change to something other than outlook.

Comment: Thunderbird has essentially unlimited filters: "There is no known limit to the number of message filters. It has been tested that even 10,000 filters can be managed properly in the Filter list dialog. However, message filters have a limit of 50 custom headers." - http://kb.mozillazine.org/Limits_(Thunderbird)#Message_filters although for true Exchange integration, a paid plugin like ExQuilla is required, otherwise you can only access Exchange with IMAP or POP3.

Comment: Unfortunately corporate policy has my machine fairly well limited.  I am stuck with Outlook.

Comment: @MackM then you are limited to the restrictions in Outlook... Maybe a inbox manager plugin can help?

Comment: You can let the items go to the inbox (no rules) then based on the same identifier as in your current rules, move the mail to the appropriate folder with VBA using ItemAdd. Sample ItemAdd code  https://superuser.com/questions/286658/how-to-run-outlook-rule-than-message-moved-to-folder It is known that receiving too many items at the same time breaks ItemAdd code.