# Save and rename an attachment from outlook 2013 to a specific folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, attachments

I have been using the steps from another post on this site and it worked for a few days and now it does not. The file always comes in from the same person and is always an xlsm attachment.

I enabled the [unsafe Client Mail Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IUMD.jpg) in outlook to enable run a script

I then created a rule that moves the email from a specific person to a subfolder under the inbox

[attachment rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP2Xq.jpg)

and then runs the following script

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "c:\Automation\CBM\"
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
Set objAtt = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

The move to the subfolder works but the saving of the attachment to the folder location no longer does.

I checked the macro setting and they are set to enable all.

I am not sure why it stopped working. it runs but after the move to subfolder nothing happens.

any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The rule might run but how do you know the code did? You could put in a MsgBox to verify. If the code is running you could put code to move the item after the attachments are saved, dropping the move from the rule.

Comment: I dont think it is executing. I adding the MsgBoxs to the code and nothing ever pops up....I also can;t run the code from the module...shows up blank

I added MsgBox "starting Code" right below Dim saveFolder As String and MsgBox "ending code" in between Next and End Sub

Comment: If there is no solution offered to this question, you could switch to ItemAdd which runs once mail moves, automatically or manually, into a specified folder. https://superuser.com/questions/286658/how-to-run-outlook-rule-than-message-moved-to-folder

Comment: I found this code and modified it to meet my needs. It is working but I am unsure how to modify it. What I would like to do is save the file as Report_ACTIVITY.xlsm everytime. Can you help with that part?

This is the link to the original code I usedhttp://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=522

Comment: You could create a new question, but since this frequently asked question need not be asked again. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43639596/saving-and-renaming-an-outlook-attachment-with-static-name

Answer (score 0):

As I can see on your screenshot and the macro you're using, the rule fires the **SaveAttachments** macro and your script is named **saveAttachtoDisk**. Maybe your rule just fires another script that does nothing?